# HTML5 Offline Single Page Application (SPA) - Security Concerns

Tags: html, knockout.js, single-page-application

We want to build an offline capable HTML5 SPA with sensitive business data.
Most likely with knockout.js!

But we have really hard security concerns.

What about encryption? Encryption may be possible. But the appropriate key has to be on the (offline) client side as well. And if you have both the algorithms plus keys on the client side you could also store it unencrypted in local storage.

What about data manipulation? It´s easy to manipulate the DOM or JavaScript objects with tools like Firebug etc.

I really love knockout but it doesn´t feel right for real world business applications.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no security expert, but if you use js to encrypt/decrypt client-sde wouldn't you have to store both public and private keys client-side? Effectively neutralizing your whole security model.

I think once you have data client-side there really is no way to keep it fully secure, you have to trust the browser to keep the state private but really to be 100% secure you either have to abandon the web or live with the consequences by redirecting to a page or destroying your state after specific time period, sending partial data to the client and relying on server side to fill in the blanks. In a sense all web pages are offline capable if you don't close the tab. Think of your banking website with all your account activity on the page, I see no distinction between that and offline js from a security point of view.

Re: Data manipulation, this really isn't a KO "feature" but JS allows you to do pretty advanced data manipulation and libraries like linq.js make things so much easier. Not quite sql but respectable none the less.

I think KO is absolutely right for real-world business applications. More broadly the browser/js/html may not be right for the level of security you are after.

Bit of a rant, Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah. I guess you are right with that. But it gets to a different level if we would use a Mobile Device Management System that comes with Security for business applications out of the box. Do you agree with that? Encryption would not be required anymore I think and data manipulation is not possible in this sandboxed environment. It´s a web app that´s only available on our tablets, not available for the public.

Comment: @tkrause - If the web app was correctly secured to a known tablet environment then certainly security is less of a concern.